# Escape "?" from rewrite rule in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to escape "?" from the below rewrite rule:

```
^/pay/$ pay.com?$1 [PT]
```

Here dynamically after `pay/`, `?_requestid=34` getting appended. I need to escape "?" and append only `_requestid=34`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "escape"? I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: You want to exclude/remove the `?`, right?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Please explain better the requests you have on input and the results you want, and check for the[QSA] flag on rewriteRules

Comment: Am actually adding a product to cart. So it is dynamically adding requestId parameter to the url...like this.."host/cart/?_requestId=21".. where as my rewrite rule is "host/cart.jsp"..So the dynamically added parameter is lost.. Currently am using [QSA] flag, which works fine..